# #if DEBUG isn't work on some device for TestFlight version

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

The below code is work for direct running, but some weird situation occur on TestFlight version. I use Debug build configuration for my archive.

There is a button show on DEBUG mode that is work properly. Tap the button is going to show a table that contains a row and tap the row will perform some action on DEBUG mode. but some weird thing happened the button is show but the row do nothing after tapping. There is a more weird thing. I have a device is work totally fine but other don't.
I have tried to add `-DDEBUG` on other swift flag but not work.

Any idea welcome.

```
#if DEBUG
// swift code ...
#endif

#ifdef DEBUG
// objc code ...
#endif
```

Comment: TestFlight is not a `DEBUG`, it's a `RELEASE` by default

Comment: @Mojtaba Hosseini You can change the mode by Edit Scheme > Archive > Build Configuration > Debug before you archiving apps and upload the archive to TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to branch out from your existing project, you need to set up a separate project target.